# UIVisualEffectView for UIBlurEffect with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

im wondering if its possible to use the UIBlurEffect with the SpriteKit?

I found this on stackoverflow, but its not working with my SpriteNodes.

```
 var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))    
 visualEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
 imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

Do anybody know if its possible? If not - any workaround or similar effect with SpriteKit?

I need something like a blurr for one of my nodes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Spritekit has [SKEffectNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skeffectnode) for such things (and incidentally SKSCene actually inherits from SKEffectNode so you can apply a filter to your whole scene).  You can apply any CIFilter as an effect on all of your subnodes.  The apple docs linked above actually show a Box Blur example:

```
let lightingNode = SKEffectNode()
let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBoxBlur",
                          withInputParameters: ["inputRadius": 20])

lightingNode.filter = blurFilter
```

You may wish to try a [CIGaussianBlur](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGaussianBlur) instead (I am pretty sure thats what UIVisualEffectView uses).

Comment: Right now im trying to add the effect to the existing SpriteNode - Can you tell me how to add the effect?

Comment: You need to parent the node inside of a SKEffectNode.  ie add the SKEffectNode to the SpriteNode's parent, and copy the position of the spritenode, remove the SpriteNode from its parent and call addChildNode to add it to the SKEffectNode.  The effect is applies to all children of the effect node.

Comment: I tried it, but the EffectNode is not visible - I dont know why :(

Comment: My SpriteNode is transparent - I want the EffectNode under my SpriteNode, so that the effect is underneath